# How to add character or a number to a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, variables, addition

I have some list like:

```
all0 = [['mortem' 'cliffi' 'gear' 'lerp' 'control']]
all1 = [['video' 'player' 'stori' 'book' 'think' 'narr' 'kill']]
```

And I want to print it out like

```
 num = 0
 print(all+num)
```

But it didn't work.
How to add a character or a number to a variable name?

Comment: Why not have a `dict` named `all` with keys `0`, `1`, ... Then you can get and set values from the dictionary with `num` easily. (Although bear in mind that `all` is a built-in function.)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I am pretty sure that you do not need nor really want it, but Python has provision for *computing* a variable name. Simply it is a rather advanced feature and the normal way is to use mappings (`dict`) or sequence (`list` or `tuple`) containers.

Here, you would use:

```
all = []
all.append([['mortem' 'cliffi' 'gear' 'lerp' 'control']])
all.append([['video' 'player' 'stori' 'book' 'think' 'narr' 'kill']])

num = 0
print(all[0])
```

BTW, this syntax is weird, because you are essentially concatenating adjacent litteral string...

But if you really, really need it you can build a interpolator of variables:

```
def getvar(name):
    if name in locals():
        return locals()[name]
    elif name in globals():
        return globals()[name]
    else:
        raise NameError(repr(name) + ' is not defined')
```

You can then do:

```
all0 = [['mortem' 'cliffi' 'gear' 'lerp' 'control']]
all1 = [['video' 'player' 'stori' 'book' 'think' 'narr' 'kill']]

num = 0

print(getvar("all%d" % num))
```

and get as expected:

```
[['mortemcliffigearlerpcontrol']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` for that.

```
eval('print(all{})'.format(num))
```

But this is really bad style. Don't do this. You should refactor your code and use `for` loops to go through your lists e.g.

```
all = [['mortem' 'cliffi' 'gear' 'lerp' 'control']]
all.append(['video' 'player' 'stori' 'book' 'think' 'narr' 'kill']) 

for l in all:
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside how bad an idea it might be (probably *really* bad), variable names are just keys in a Python dict. A one-line solution might be:

> vars()[new_name] = vars().pop(old_name)

for global variables, and

> vars(some_obj)[new_name] = vars(some_obj).pop(old_name)

for variables of some_obj object.